# How to print a variable using var_dump in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, var-dump

```
<form>
    Main 
       <select name="main">
               <option value="a">A</option>
               <option value="b">B</option>
               <option value="c">C</option>
               <option value="d">D</option>
       </select>
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order">
</form>
```

How do I output the user's selected option using var_dump in php? And does $_POST work?

Comment: please make the post more a bit cleaner
and format the code neat and clean

Comment: it is a html form code. i want to ask how to output the option that user chose through php code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below Code.You have made some mistake like the option values are set wrongly.Inside the form tag it is advisable to use the `action and method` attribute.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $mainValue = $_POST['main'];//Retrieve the Option Value;
        echo var_dump($mainValue);//Use var_dump
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    Main 
    <select name="main">
        <option value="A">a</option>
        <option value="B">b</option>
        <option value="C"></option>
        <option value="D">d</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: I used your code but it outputs some array type and values. I only want to see the result that user chosen in the form after press the submit. -_-"

Comment: var_dump() function returns the data type and value,so it looks like.Since you want to use var_dump I have written like this. echo $mainValue; to get the submitted value.

Comment: when i press submit, it has no change.

Comment: Inside the if write only                                                                  $mainValue = $_POST['main'];echo $mainValue;

Answer (score 0):

form action attribute tag means where the form shall be submitted when submit button is press

form method attribute tag means type of server request method being requested

```
<form action="" method= "POST">
Main <select name="main">
  A <option value = "A">a</option>
  B <option value=="B">b</option>
  C <option value= ="C">c</option>
  D <option value ="D">d</option>
</select>

<br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order">
</form>


<?php 

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // this will print information about the content of the form
        // being submitted
        var_dump($_POST);
        // or
        echo '<br/>';
        print_r($_POST);

    }

?>
```